# How to get the content of the AppendedData part in the .vtp file?

Tags: python, vtk

It is my .vtp file. In this file, I only copy part of the data content because it is too long.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="PolyData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt32" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <PolyData>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="60776"                NumberOfVerts="0"                    NumberOfLines="0"                    NumberOfStrips="0"                    NumberOfPolys="121548"              >
      <PointData>
      </PointData>
      <CellData Scalars="Label">
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Label" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="2"                    offset="0"                   >
        </DataArray>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" RangeMin="14.866174942"         RangeMax="38.687086568"         offset="1748"                />
      </Points>
      <Verts>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="710424"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="710440"              />
      </Verts>
      <Lines>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="710456"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="710472"              />
      </Lines>
      <Strips>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="710488"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="710504"              />
      </Strips>
      <Polys>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="710520"              />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="1288164"             />
      </Polys>
    </Piece>
  </PolyData>
  <AppendedData encoding="base64">
   _DwAAAACAAAAwawAANAAAADQA
  </AppendedData>
</VTKFile>
```

After I used the annotation software to annotate, I got this file. I hope to obtain these tags explicitly to help me use them in subsequent training.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use ssh to connect to a laptop on port 24
Use a admin laptop go to cmd
type in ssh -L admin (ip adress)  <to log into the core server
dmz, edge and backbone
Show lldp neighbors all devices
check if they are encrypted
check the i consol cables work

Interface vlan 1 ip adress
no shutdown

---

hostname
ip domain-name
crypto key generate rsa
1024
ip ssh version 2
username admin password
line vty 0 4
transport input ssh
login local

Comment: And neither does this. Are you trying to answer a different question?

Answer (score -2):

ip dhcp pool ….
Network 192.168.50.0 2555.255.255.0
Default-router 192…
Ip dhcp exculuded

Show ip nat translations

Interface range fastethernet0/1-12
Switchport access vlan 10
Show running-config
Show vlan brief

Interface Gigabitethernet0/1
No shutdown

interface gigabitethernet0/1
switchtport trunk allowed vlan 5,20,20 etc.

Show interfaces trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan remove(addd) 20

Spanning tree vlan priority 4096

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the question being asked.